# Change notification text in Notification Center

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing an iOS app which receive push notification from GCM server. I need to change the message received from push notification server to "You have received n notification" where n will be number of notification received from push server.

Is there is a way to perform this action?

If yes, then how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, **but you must maintain the count of unopened notifications yourself**. You could have your app send a HTTP request to your server when the app opens, to set to zero the message count on your server, which will increment with each new message till the app is opened and the value is reset. So when you send a new message you can include the incremented value in the message.